# Django: do I need to restart Apache when deploying?

Tags: python, django

I just noted an annoying factor: Django requires either a restart of the server or [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) access to work. The first option is not feasible if you don't have access to the Apache server process. The second, as far as I know, is detrimental to performance, and in general the idea of running a CGI makes me uncomfortable.

I also recently saw a presentation titled "why I hate Django". Although I did not really shared most of the speaker's (a Flickr guy) points, this fact of re-starting the server sounded very annoying.

I would like to know your motivated experience in this regard. Should I continue working with Django and use it as a CGI, or favor another Python framework ? Is the CGI option that bad, and should I be concerned about it, or it's a viable option (for performance and scalability) ?

Comment: Note that Cal Henderson's talk on why he hates Django was *a keynote at DjangoCon*, so clearly he doesn't hate it all that much. Many of his "hates" were sarcastic, or at least meant in the sense 'could do better'.

Comment: It's still better than Java web development. You must restart server and wait much longer.

Comment: @Daniel: yes, but some of his points were good, some other were sarcastic to the limit of being inappropriate. I do understand he is a scalability guy, but complaining about spaces and tabs and the stuff that goes on the wire it's a bit excessive... if you reach this level of sarcasm, your audience start wondering how much sarcastic or real is everything else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the WSGI standard, through [`mod_wsgi`](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/). You don't have to restart Apache, merely update the mtime on the .wsgi file.

Comment: This assumes the server uses this apache module I guess.

Comment: How else would you hook up Django to Apache? Are you using something crazy like mod_python?

Comment: I won't beat you -- using mod_python is its own punishment. But you could solve your problems easily by using mod_wsgi instead. Here's some guides: < http://ericholscher.com/blog/2008/jul/8/setting-django-and-mod_wsgi/ >, < http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango >

Comment: Can we use mod_wsgi with non-Apache server?

Comment: No, mod_wsgi is an Apache module — although, confusingly, there is a ‘mod_wsgi’ for nginx which is an unrelated codebase. WSGI is the standard you write applications to; mod_wsgi is just glue to attach it to Apache. For a different web server, you'd use different glue, but the application itself would not need changing.

Answer (score 0):

I usually don't restart the server, but force-reload the configuration. On an Ubuntu Hardy server, that is

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 force-reload
```

and it's done almost immediately.

Answer (score 0):

For how to deal with source code reloading when using Apache/mod_wsgi, read:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2008/12/using-modwsgi-when-developing-django.html

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/02/source-code-reloading-with-modwsgi-on.html

Documentation is more useful when it is read. ;-)

Comment: If you have some time, consider fixing the post by including relevant information in the answer itself, and link to the referenced site. Link-only answers will become invalid when the linked page changes.